# How large is the attributes can a class object hold? how to determine the stack/heap limit?

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator, limit

I have a class which requiring a large amount of memory.

```
class BigClass {
public:
    BigClass() {
        bf1[96000000-1] = 1;
    }
    double bf1[96000000];
};
```

I can only initiate the class by "new" a object in heap memory.

```
BigClass *c = new BigClass();
assert( c->bf1[96000000-1] == 1 );
delete c;
```

If I initiate it without "new". I will get a segmentation fault in runtime.

```
BigClass c; // SIGSEGV!
```

How can I determine the memory limit? or should I better always use "new"?

Comment: just a guess that the limit may actually come from the heap that is provided by the OS when the program is running

Comment: @clamp You should not confuse the heap memory (used by the `new` operator) with the stack memory used for automatic variables as in `BigClass c;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack have a fixed size that is dependant on the compiler options. See your compiler documentation to change the stack size for your executable.

Anyway, for big objects, prefer using new or better : smart pointers like shared_pointer (from boost or from std::tr1 or std:: if you have very recent compiler).

Answer (score 3):

First of all since you've entitled this C++ and not C why are you using arrays?  Instead may I suggest `vector<double>` or, if contiguous memory is causing problems `deque<double>` which relaxes the constraint on contiguous memory without removing the nearly constant time lookup.

Using `vector` or `deque` may also alleviate other seg fault issues which could plague your project at a later date.  For instance, overrunning bounds in your array.  If you convert to using `vector` or `deque` you can use the `.at(x)` member function to retrieve and set values in your collection.  Should you attempt to write out of bounds, that function will throw an error.

Comment: In addition, if using `vector`, you may want to call `vector::reserve` if you'll be using that much memory.

Comment: @user470379 good point but only if you need to do `push_back`.  I think the sizes here will be static.

Comment: @wheaties, however your second paragraph seems off-base. The most likely explanation for the segmentation fault is that a single `BigClass` instance is larger than the remaining stack space.

Comment: @wheaties Explain why the static size makes a difference. AFAIK `reserve` is the only way to reserve space for elements without actually initializing them.

Comment: @Jon-Eric you're right.  I most likely is that the item is too large to place on the stack.  I'll remove that.

Comment: @user470379 you use `reserve` generally when you want to have the option of appending more items to your list while avoiding the copy overhead of transcribing an old vector contiguous array to the newer, larger version.  Here, it appears that the OP wants a statically sized rather than a dynamically sized array.  Vectors allow you within the constructor call to set a specific size at construction.

Comment: The vector constructor only allow you to specify the size if you also provide a value with which it initializes each and every member. If you'll be filling the vector with your data, initializing every member is wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no platform-independent way of determining the memory limit.  For "large" amounts of memory, you're far safer allocating on the heap (i.e. using `new`); you can check for success by comparing the resulting pointer against `NULL`, or catching `std::bad_alloc` exceptions.

Comment: Careful, depending on the allocator used, `operator new` can also throw a `bad_alloc` exception instead of returning `NULL` on failure. See the C++ spec, ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E) section 5.3.4.13.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't play that game ever. Your code could be called from another function or on a thread with a lower stack size limit and then your code will break nastily. See [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345478/how-to-detect-the-amount-of-stack-space-available-to-my-program).

If you're in doubt use heap-allocation (`new`) - either directly with smart pointers (like `auto_ptr`) or indirectly using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The way your class is designed is, as you discovered, quite fragile. Instead of always allocating your objects on the heap, instead your class itself should allocate the huge memory block on the heap, preferably with `std::vector`, or possibly with a `shared_ptr` if `vector` doesn't work for some reason. Then you don't have to worry about how your clients use the object, it's safe to put on the stack or the heap.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, in the Bash shell, you can check the stack size with `ulimit -s`. Variables with automatic storage duration will have their space allocated on the stack. As others have said, there are better ways of approaching this:

1. Use a `std::vector` to hold your data inside your `BigClass`.
2. Allocate the memory for `bf1` inside `BigClass`'s constructor and then free it in the destructor.
3. If you *must* have a large `double[]` member, allocate an instance of BigClass with some kind of [smart pointer](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html); if you don't need shared access something as simple as `std::auto_ptr` will let you safely construct/destroy your object:

   ```
   std::auto_ptr<BigClass>(new BigClass) myBigClass;
   myBigClass->bf1; // your array
   ```